# How can I append array using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have two select box.

```
<select id="select-1"><option value="one">one</option><option value="two">two</option></select>
<select id="select-2"></select>
```

When I select value one it will append option list using List array

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('#select-1').on('change', function() {
    var List = ["test 1", "test 2", "test 3", "test 4"];
    var selectedVal = $(this).children("option:selected").val();
    if(selectedVal == "one") {
      $('#select-2').append('<option>' +  List + '</option>');
    }  else {
     //
    }
  })
});
</script>
```

It load option list like

```
<option>test 1 test 2 test 3 test 4</option>
```

but it must be

```
<option>test 1</option><option>test 2</option><option>test 3</option><option>test 4</option>
```

how can I fix this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this succinctly would be to use `map()` to build a HTML string of `option` elements from the array which you can append:

```js
jQuery($ => {
  $('#select-1').on('change', function() {
    let list = ["test 1", "test 2", "test 3", "test 4"];
    if ($(this).val() === "one") {
      let options = list.map(t => `<option>${t}</option>`).join('');
      $('#select-2').append(options);
    } else {
      $('#select-2').empty();
    }
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="select-1">
  <option value="">Select...</option>
  <option value="one">one</option>
  <option value="two">two</option>
</select>
<select id="select-2"></select>
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably want a `for` or a `forEach` loop:

```
if (selectedVal == "one") {
    List.forEach(item => {
        $('#select-2').append('<option>' +  item + '</option>');
    }
}
```

Comment: Rory's answer is more complete and will offer better performance/scalability. Use that one instead